# Does only one John de Lancie Q exist in the multiverse?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-q

As shown in various episodes ("Mirror, Mirror," "Phantasms," etc.), other universes exist, oftentimes containing the same characters, albeit in different situations than in the prime universe. I'm curious, though, whether individuals that apparently exist outside of the multiverse, such as members of the Q, would not be duplicated elsewhere. It seems reasonable to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/M_Continuum

Comment: Well, technically, the M Continuum is not a part of the Q Continuum. I was looking for canon answers or suggestions.

Comment: I wasn't a big fan of I, Q. I own the book. I want a book where Q has his powers the entire time and just goes around tormenting individuals and other races!

Comment: You'd enjoy "Iridium-7 Tetrahydroxate Crystals Are A Girl's Best Friend"; http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DlPNd1hrh1sC&pg=PA207&lpg=PA207&dq=Iridium-7+Tetrahydroxate+Crystals+Are+A+Girl%27s+Best+Friend&source=bl&ots=99ShSgJz0T&sig=7qpyIkqn4hlRQjRvFNyS-NhtAJU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AhhMVJXYLIWR7AaWpYHYDw&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Iridium-7%20Tetrahydroxate%20Crystals%20Are%20A%20Girl's%20Best%20Friend&f=false

Comment: If you accept the events in "Tapestry" actually occurred, it appears that Q can travel between different universes, and is the same throughout the multiverse.

Comment: Given his control of alternate timelines (and therefore parallel universes), I'd say it's a given that Q exists across all universes.

Comment: In the book "Q Squared", an alternate Trelane attacks our universe's Trelane, implying that there are separate versions of them in each universe.  It appears that they can travel between universes as well.  I don't know that this question has an answer that is fully consistent with ST canon as I don't believe canon is internally consistent on this subject.

Comment: It seems to me, that the Q can manipulate space and time at will, jumping from reality to reality. They basically have the code of the universe at their fingertips and exist anywhere they want. I think that's why Q tapped Picard and the Federation to help fight off the Borg - that particular time and place was where he needed to kick them in their complacency so the Borg don't overrun the multiverse. Just a guess though.

Comment: "M" and "Q", hmm. Is there a Moneypenny continuum?

Comment: What I want to know is, how many different John de Lancie Qs visited how many of the 285,000+ Enterprise Ds seen/implied in the TNG episode Parallels.  And what was the outcome in his shenanigans in each of them?

Answer (score 12):

### TV Canon

Q has demonstrated the ability to transcend multiple time-streams in the episode [TNG: All Good Things](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/All_Good_Things..._%28episode%29) where

> Picard inadvertently destroys the human race through the creation of a temporal paradox.

It also appears that the  Q continuum itself exists outside the normal "multiverse" seen within the Star Trek universe with Quinn noting that the "dusty road" (seen in VOY: Death Wish) leads to the universe.

### Comic canon

This issue was discussed by [Trek writer Mike Johnson](http://io9.gizmodo.com/q-stops-by-j-j-abrams-new-star-trek-universe-to-make-t-1564357914) after the appearance of Q in the new Star Trek timeline (in the ongoing comic serial "[The Q Gambit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LALSJYM)"):

> **He's definitely the Q we know from The Next Generation, correct?**
>
> **MJ:** *Indeed. The Q Continuum exists outside of the alternate timelines that our tiny flesh-brains occupy. **Every Q is the same Q
>   across all parallel realities,** and this Q maintains both his
>   fascination with and his contempt for the human species in
>   particular.*
>
> **Is this technically set before Q has met Picard and the others in TNG?**
>
> **MJ:** *After. In this new story, Q has already had all of the adventures we've seen in the television series over the years, and
>   he's aware that Spock Prime (Leonard Nimoy) traveled from the old
>   timeline to the new one.*
>
> **So does this mean there['s] a Q in the new-Trek universe, or is there only the one?**
>
> **MJ:** *Maaaaaaybe.*

### In-Universe Reference texts

The [Star Trek Encyclopedia](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Encyclopedia) directly refers to the Q as being **extradimensional** rather than existing within any specific dimension or universe:

> **Q, (John DeLancie) :** ***An immensely powerful extradimensional entity.***
>   While possessing near-godlike powers. Q also exhibits a childlike
>   petulance and sense of playfulness

Answer (score 0):

I think that Q goes beyond just the normal universes. In Star Trek Voyager he goes back to just before the Big Bang of our own universe. So I don't think that Q would be duplicated elsewhere.

Comment: Can you provide any evidence why you thin Q wouldn't be duplicated simply because he can go "beyond" the normal universes. Is there reason to believe only one of him can exist.